# Vmware Always Keep Black Screen with Ubuntu16

Tags: vmware

when i open ubuntu16.0.4 with wmware in Desktop.exe's second screen, i meet a error,the vmware always keep black,i found a lot solutions but not resolve the question.

all in all ,open vmware always black screen on second screen using Desktop.exe

Comment: What is the host OS? Does "second screen" mean like a second monitor or like a multi-desktop env? What is Desktop.exe? Which solutions have you already tried?

Comment: windows7，Desktop.exe is tool of windows Sysinternals Live, allows you to organize your applications on up to four virtual desktops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, i found in windows7 ,when i open vmware not in first screen with Destops.exe, the vmware can not show normal image, and when it hang, it can show normal image

All in all, must open vmware in first screen